# How do I form a new string from a parsed CSV line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, csv

I'm using bash shell.  I have a CSV file in which each line's tokens are separated by commas.  I want to take the second and third columns and forma  new string out of them (an SQL statement).  I thought I could use awk for this purpose, so I tried ...

```
localhost:mydir davea$ awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' "REPLACE INTO my_table (ID, NAME, HOURS) VALUES ('$2', '$2', '$3');" types.csv
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    REPLACE INTO my_table >>>  (ID, <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

but as you can see I'm getting an error.  Am I leaving something out?  How do I form my new string from each line in the CSV file?

Comment: Good catch.  But even when I change it to "awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' "{print REPLACE INTO my_table (ID, NAME, HOURS) VALUES ('$2', '$2', '$3');}" types.csv", I get the same syntax error as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F ',' '{
    printf("REPLACE INTO my_table (ID, NAME, HOURS) VALUES ('\''%s'\'', '\''%s'\'', '\''%s'\'');\n", $2, $2, $3) 
}' types.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting single quotes inside of a single quoted string is really tedious. Here, I'm passing a single quote into the the awk variable "q". I'm also trying to take care of [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com).

```
awk -F ',' -v q="'" '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(q, q q, $i)
        print "REPLACE INTO my_table (ID, NAME, HOURS) VALUES (" q $1 q "," q $2 q "," q $3 q");"
    }
' <<END
foo,bar,Robert');DROP TABLE students;--
END
```

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (ID, NAME, HOURS) VALUES ('foo','bar','Robert'');DROP TABLE students;--');
```

Comment: drop table? sounds like a joke

Comment: follow the link in my answer...

Comment: +1 for `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(q, q q, $i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be not the most efficient solution but shall work:

```
awk  -F, '{print "REPLACE INTO my_table (ID, NAME, HOURS) VALUES (\x27"$2"\x27,\x27"$2"\x27,\x27"$3"\x27);"}' types.csv
```